# Sometimes prints one line, and sometimes prints three lines

Tags: c++, multithreading

Running the multithreaded C++ code given below sometimes print "XYZ" one time on the standard output as expected but sometimes the output consists of three lines of "XYZ" on the standard output. Will somebody elaborate on why this is happening as I am new to multithreading concepts?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>

void f(std::string s)
{

  std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

void not_oops()
{
  f( "XYZ");
  std::string buffer="XYZ";
  std::thread t(f,buffer);
  t.detach();
}
int main()
{
  not_oops();
}
```

Platform:- Ubuntu 18.04

Compiler:- g++ 7.4.0

Command while compiling the code:- g++ -pthread main.cpp

Comment: Why is one time the expected output? Please explain that.

Comment: Because detach() method has been called on std::thread object 't' and according to my limited multithreading knowledge the function 'not_oops()' when called in 'main()' shouldn't wait for std::thread object 't' to finish its computation and exit after printing "XYZ" only one time. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are wrong, there is nothing preventing the second thread from running and finishing. There are no implicit guarantees about thread progress.

Comment: I don't understand _three lines_. There is one call of `f()` in `not_oops()` and another in `std::thread t` (which may or may not be called before process exits). Where does the third line come from? Do I oversee something?

Comment: So why "XYZ" is being printed three times. If the thread has finished its computation than also "XYZ" should've been printed two and not three times.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. I got two lines output: [**test on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7350895979f1bc0). (Note: I don't consider `sleep_for()` as a sufficient sync. facility but `1s` seems long enough for this test in average case.)

Comment: Out of curiosity: What do you get if you apply this change: `std::string buffer="T: XYZ";`? [**test on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b676f7907e2785c5)

Comment: If the thread has finished its computation than, XYZ
T: XYZ
T: XYZ

Comment: That's strange. Especially, because coliru seems to run on Ubuntu as well... [**test on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48dd5d36368b9bed)

Comment: Did you add the `sleep_for()` as I did in my test?

Comment: Do you get it as well if you replace `t.detach();` by `t.join();`?

Comment: I mean, detaching a thread and then exiting the program/process is nothing which introduces any reliable technique which can be used in productive code later for anything... ;-)

Comment: No, I haven't added sleep_for(). Will you elaborate on what this does? And as for replacing 't.detach()' with 't.join()' it does give the expected output of printing "XYZ" two times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `detach` can cause your observations, and can be explained as you encountering races.

When you only observe one line of output, it is because the spawning of the new thread is racing against the process exiting. If it doesn't spawn in time, only the output generated by the main thread will be shown.

When you observe three lines of output, it is because `cout` is being flushed by multiple threads. Since `cout` is not thread safe, it is possible that the main thread is executing the global destructor at the same time the spawned thread is printing. Both believe the internal stream buffer has something to flush, and so the content gets shown twice.

When you use `join` instead, the main thread waits for the spawned thread to complete before ending the program, eliminating the race condition. So, you only observe two lines of output, as expected.